# Python prints "none" in output

Tags: python

In my code below, I am trying to print all numbers in a string. The output prints 10, 20, 30, None. I understand the "None"is printed because I am not "return"anything in the function. How do i best re-write this code to avoid "none" being output.

```py
import re

def myfunc(string):
    patterns=r'\d+'
    array=re.findall(patterns,string)
    for n in array:
        print(n)

print(myfunc("Ten 10, Twenty 20, Thirty 30"))
```

Comment: Just call `myfunc("Ten 10, Twenty 20, Thirty 30")` instead of `print(myfunc("Ten 10, Twenty 20, Thirty 30"))`, if you don't want to print the `None` that it returns.

Comment: You are printing the return statement of the `myfunc` function, which is `None`...

Answer (score 2):

The cause is that a `return` is missing from the function.

Otherwise, there is an implicit `return None` in every function.

Either leave-off the bottommost `print()` or have the function return a useful value.

Comment: Perhaps refrain from answering obvious FAQs and instead close as a duplicate.

Comment: @triplee For new posters, how about erring on the side of being nice.  You don't have to be harsh to newcomers or you don't have to edit-out minor pleasantries.

Comment: Duplicates are not "harsh", they typically have several well-vetted answers that probably help the newcomer more than a tired routine recapitulation of the standard answer.

Comment: @tripleee From the point of view of the OP, they likely didn't know enough to find or recognize the other answer.  I don't object this being closed as a duplicate, but it wasn't wrong for me to help with his or problem, nor was it wrong to be nice about it.  We're trying to make StackOverflow a better place and to give especially welcoming to newcomers.  You don't have to be on-board with that, but you don't have to stomp on others who are trying to make the environment more pleasant.